# Show number of affected blocks using CFB DES decryption of altered ciphertext

Tags: des, cfb, error-propagation

I have encrypted a file using `-des -cfb` and now I want to view how many blocks it contains once I decrypt it.

I have done this on the Linux terminal. I know that 9 blocks will be effected if there is an error in the ciphertext.

I need to show proof that this is true. But I'm unsure how to do this in a Linux terminal.

Comment: Where does the 9 come from?

Comment: If there is an error in the ciphertext transmission c1 9 blocks will be corrupted during the decyption . How can I show that it is 9. (64/8 = 8, +1 = 9)

Comment: @PaulUszak This seems to come from a course on crypto, see my answer for a link to a previous question.

Answer (score 1):

Block size = 1 byte for CFB thus 9 bytes are affected. Why this is true [has been answered before](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/59008/1172). Even for CFB8 it takes 8 shifts to shift the wrong ciphertext value out of the buffer.

To proof this is true just change a single byte of a binary output file using a hex editor (`hexedit`) and then decrypt. Count the number of differing number of bytes (`diff`). If you get 8 bytes then the last byte refused to budge - it may regenerate the same value *by chance*. Redo from start, multiple times if you want "statistical proof".

Comment: Ugh, did I write "statistical proof"? Help, I'm turning alpha!

Comment: Note that this is an assignment and that this is not a Unix Q/A site, I have left out the *explicit* commands that you're required to perform.